# Use JavaScript Variable in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I want to use this below variable reqID into my java code, and I want to submit this prompt with this value. And that value i want to use in update.

```
function approveReset(){
    var reqID = prompt("Enter Request ID : ", "Request ID");
    <%
        try{
            -- Here i want to call my variable reqID--
            PreparedStatement ps_approve_req = conn.prepareStatement("<Some update statement>");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Some issue happened hence rolling back.");
            conn.rollback();
        }
    %>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "Call my variable"?

Comment: You must sent request to the server with the value in the QueryString or with request body? but how server-side can call client-side?

Comment: The scriptlet will be executed on the server-side when the jsp is loaded the way you are trying to execute the scriptlet inside a javascript function won't work the way you intended.

Comment: I will be calling this function by clicking on a link, so please help me how i can do this.

Comment: My requirement is if i click on link it will prompt for request ID and with that request ID i want to update the table in DB.